# How to customize disk space unit of install location dialog?

Tags: install4j

We want to setup the disk space unit from MB to GB. Is there any option to switch the unit? Or is it only possible to change the label itself within an pre-activation script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, the value will always be displayed in MB. I've created an issue for 6.0, so that the displayed value automatically switches to GB if the free disk space is large enough.