# How to change disk space unit of install Location screen?

Tags: install4j

We wanted to display "Required disk space" and "Free disk space" with unit GB. But it displays disk space in MB (eg. 3014 MB) instead of 3 GB. Is there any way to change the unit from MB to GB? Current I am using the latest version of install4j 7.0.9.

I found the same question has been asked previously.

[How to customize disk space unit of install location dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516604/how-to-customize-disk-space-unit-of-install-location-dialog)

Answer is above provided link specifies that issue will get resolved in install4j version 6.0. But issue still exists in install4j version 7.0.9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize disk space unit of install location dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516604/how-to-customize-disk-space-unit-of-install-location-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 6.0, the disk space is displayed in GB if the value is more than 10 GB. So "3014 MB" is displayed as intended.

Comment: Thank you Ingo, But still I would like to know is there any way to display Free space from 1-9 in GB using built-in actions, if not could you please suggest any other way to resolve it.

Comment: No, there is currently no way to do that.